# Rank 2 constraint programming / constraint implication

Tags: haskell, types

```
import Data.Constraint

reify :: (c' :- c) -> (c => a) -> (c' => a)
reify cons f = case cons of Sub d -> case d of Dict -> f
```

Using `reify`, I can weaken a constraint `c` to a constraint `c'` given proof that `c'` implies `c`.

Now, I want a `Rank2` variant of this:

```
-- reify2 Rank2's reify
reify2 :: (forall r1. c' r1 :- c r1) -> 
          (forall r2. c r2 => a) -> 
          (forall r3. c' r3 => a)
reify2 cons f = ???
```

But I'm unable to implement such a function, even though it must "clearly" be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguity can be lifted using `ScopedTypeVariables+TypeApplications`, although you need to reorder the arguments of `reify2`, putting the type arguments first to put them in scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, TypeOperators #-}

data Dict c where
  Dict :: c => Dict c

data c :- d where
  Sub :: (c => Dict d) -> c :- d

reify2 :: forall r3 c c' a. c' r3 =>
          (forall r1. c' r1 :- c r1) ->
          (forall r2. c r2 => a) ->
          a
reify2 cons f =
  case cons @r3 of
    Sub Dict -> f @r3
```

Comment: Thanks! What would a proof that `reify2` is isomorphic to the original look like? I'm not 100% convinced that they implement the same function.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to do in Haskell because there's so much ambiguity to resolve, and I'm not sure how to implement the original signature. But for example in Coq where `=>` is `->` plus some bells and whistles, and `->` in turn is just sugar for `forall`, one can be obtained from the other literally by reordering arguments. `fun c c' a myreify2 cons f r3 Hc'r3 => myreify2 r3 c c' a Hc'r3 cons f`.